# How to resolve this error Field 'STATE_REGION' doesn't have a default value in MySQl 5.6

Tags: mysql-5.6, mysql-error-1364

I had an error like the following

> Field **'STATE_REGION' - Field Name** doesn't have a default value in
>   MySQL 5.6.

I fixed the issue by changing `sql_mode = '';` in previous version of MySQL

But failed in MySQL 5.6

How to fix this issue in MySQL 5.6. Please help any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Got Solution To my Problem
Just add IGNORE after INSERT

INSERT IGNORE INTO tblname(....

["INSERT IGNORE" vs "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

Thanks:)